# Push into vector in reverse order

Tags: c++, stl

How can I push the byes in a `char[]` array into a `std::vector<char>` in reverse order? e.g. I want to push

```
char c[] = "a string";
```

into

```
std::vector<char> v;
```

so that in the end `v` will contain

```
{'g','n','i','r','t','s',' ','a'}
```

?

Comment: Use `std::reverse_copy`.

Comment: @chris Does `reverse_copy` push them into the array (allocating space as needed) or do I need to pre-allocate space according to the string length?

Comment: It pushes them into the vector if you use a `std::back_inserter`

Comment: It effectively calls `push_back` on parent container. Note that in case of longer strings this will result in vector gradually resizing itself (multiple allocations) rather than allocating as much space as it needs one time only. `std::back_inserter` has no notion of underlying container's size

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::string cString(c);
std::vector<char> v(cString.rbegin(), cString.rend());
```

or

```
v.insert(v.end(), cString.rbegin(), cString.rend());
```

for existing vector.

Comment: Which is the correct solution, except that he's starting with a `char[]`.

Comment: I am appending to an existing vector, not creating a new one

Comment: @baruch then you can use `v.insert(v.end(), cString.rbegin(), cString.rend())`.

Answer (score 4):

With reverse iterators:

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<const char*> r_it;
std::vector<char> v ( r_it(std::end(c)), r_it(std::begin(c)) );
```

In C++14, we'll be able to do

```
std::vector<char> v( std::crbegin(c), std::crend(c) );
```

To append to an existing vector, use

```
v.insert( v.end(), rbegin, rend );
```

Comment: And of course, if you don't even have C++11, you should at least have the equivalent of `std::begin` and `std::end` in your tool kit.

Comment: @JamesKanze And even `crbegin` and `crend`, I'd say.

Comment: I think this moves the NUL terminator to the front. You have to write `std::prev(std::end(c))`.

Comment: @Simple It does. There's no other way around that but to put either an ugly `+1/-1` or a verbose `std::next/std::prev` somewhere. I leave that choice to OP :)

Comment: Also, because he doesn't want the `'\0'`,  it should be `std::end(c) - 1`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Simple Except that the "iterator" returned by `std::end(c)` in this case is a pointer, so `std::endc(c) - 1` is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @jrok Curiously enough, I've never needed them, so they aren't there.  But I'd certainly add them if I needed them (as the poster does here).

Answer (score 4):

If don't feel like using std::string (avoiding allocation etc.) you can use `reverse_iterator` explicitly. I use helper function cause I hate specifying template parameters explicitly:

```
template <class It>
std::reverse_iterator<It> make_reverse(It it)
{
    return std::reverse_iterator<It>(it);
}

...

char c[] = "a string";
std::vector<char> v( make_reverse(std::end(c)) + 1, make_reverse(std::begin(c)) );
```

The `+1` is there because you want to skip the trailing `\0` from `c`.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use `reverse_copy`:

```
char c[] = ...;
std::vector<char> vec;
// Avoid to copy the terminating '\0': Don't add +1 to strlen(c)
std::reverse_copy(c, c+strlen(c), std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Comment: Won't that result in vector allocating memory multiple times?

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably initialize the vector using `sizeof`.

Comment: Depends on the actual implementation of the std library, but most allocate more space than needed to provide amortized `O(1)` insertion cost. So it might well be that it only allocates once, if the input string is short. But you may of course reserve enough space in the vector beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
[...]

char c[] = "a string";
std::vector<char> v;

std::reverse_copy(c, c + sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Thanks to chris for originally suggesting reverse_copy in the comments.

Note that with this approach you will get a `'\0'` in the first element of your vector.

Comment: Isn't that would be with a '\0' char?